# Variable doesn't exist outside code

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

This is my code for an XMLHttpRequest to get data from a PHP page. When I alert the variable user_data inside an "if" it works. But below all of this code the variable doesn't exist any more.

Thanks for the help!

```
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    user_data = xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert (user_data); //THIS WORKS
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://myurl.com/index.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
alert (user_data); //THIS DOESN'T WORK
```

Comment: That's because Ajax is asynchronous. The `onreadystatechange` callback is called only when the request has completed, after your second alert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an asynchronous request.  The non-working alert is executed before the request returns.  The variable isn't assigned until the request completes.

Answer (score 0):

It's gone out of scope

```
var user_data = null;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    user_data = xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert (user_data); //THIS WORKS
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://myurl.com/index.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Don't forget to check it for null when you reference it again.

Answer (score 0):

`xmlhttp.send();` your control starts your request execution and then and moves to `onreadystatechange=function()` block as soon as some response to this request.

Comment: What can I do to get the var out of the function?

Comment: define user_data as global. Use call back function and set your value to user_data there. Then you can alert.